# Get deleted item into a consecutive Python list

Tags: python, list, indexing, items

Like to know the missing numbers in given list [0,1,2,3,5,6,7] or [0,2,3,4,5,6,7], or [1,3,4,5,7,9] and take the current index. Some help there?

Comment: It's unclear what output you want. Can you provide an example? Also, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you need the indexes or the missing values. Based on the question title "Get deleted item", I'm deducing you want the values (no indexes).

I'd use sets for this:

```
>>> skips = [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 14, 15, 16]
>>> skippedValues = set(range(min(skips), max(skips)+1)) - set(skips)
>>> print skippedValues
set([8, 11, 3, 12, 13])
>>> print list(skippedValues)
[8, 11, 3, 12, 13]
```

Note that this solution works even if your list isn't sorted.

Comment: Thanks! Im wondering if this solve the problem with 0 and the out of range index for a looped list.

Comment: Probably you won't find any "out of range index", since python is doing everything for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method for finding the indices of any skips:

```
skips = [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 14, 15, 16]

skipIndices = [k for k in range(1, len(skips)) if skips[k-1]+1 <> skips[k]]

print skipIndices

# output:  [3, 7, 9]
```

Comment: what about for `skips = [3,5,6]`? Yours requires the range to start at 0

Comment: If `skips = [3, 5, 6]`, then the output is `[1]`, i.e. the index of the first skip is `1`.  I interpreted "take the current index" as in the OP wants the indices of the skips.

Comment: oh, I misinterpreted your interpretation :P

Answer (score 0):

will work for any list `skips`

```
>>> skips = [2,3,6,7,10]
>>> [x for x in range(min(skips), max(skips)) if x not in skips]
[4, 5, 8, 9]
```